# Mailchimp error 400 request, can't send users to list

Tags: android, post, android-volley, mailchimp

I'm working with Mailchimp and I want to send an email address to my list, I have done this so far with Volley:

```
public void suscribeMailChamp(){
    String listid = "listID";
    String url = "https://us16.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + listid + "/members/";
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "success" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , error.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email_address","testmailchimp@gmail.com");
            params.put("status","unsubscribed");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            params.put("Authorization" , "apikey <here my api key>");
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(sr);
}
```

but I get error 400:

> Unexpected response code 400 for
>   https://us16.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/b9a5943047/members/

Here is a link for troubleshooting but I can't get the error:

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the error in the link? It says

```
{  
   "type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
   "title":"API Key Missing",
   "status":401,
   "detail":"Your request did not include an API key.",
   "instance":"924c81cc-90e9-498d-b0fd-c7b54cba207f"
}
```

which means you are not (or correctly) sending the API key for mail chimp in the request. Just add the mailChimp API key in the params for `Volley` request

---

So the way you would send your API key is this

```
params.put("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.encodeToString(("apikey:"+apiKey).getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.DEFAULT))
```

Comment: im sending it here params.put("Authorization" , "apikey myapikey");

Comment: also you are telling me what is in the link and i already readed that

Comment: No I am saying you are sending the API key in a wrong way. Let me see the docs

Comment: Try doing this for authorization param `params.put("Authorization", "Basic apikey:<here my api key>")`

Comment: with params.put("Authorization", "apikey <here my api key>");  i get error 404

Comment: One of the Java wrappers for MailChimp is using Base64 encoding in sending the request. Looking at their request method, maybe this might work for you `params.put("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.encodeToString("apikey: <here my api key>".getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.DEFAULT));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163195/discussion-between-napster-and-void).

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck at this too. Mailchimp documentation is very poor. 
I found the solution [from github](https://github.com/mailchimp/APIv3-examples/issues/41)

Just send 'Authorization': 'apikey myapikey' in your header